# Generate random string based on custom pattern in C#

Tags: c#, code-generation

I want to be able to generate random strings based on custom pattern set from the user using `Console.ReadLine();`

Example: !!!!-##!?-?!!# ( ! = number, # - Upper letter and ? = Lower letter), then generates a string and returns it using `Console.WriteLine();`

I tried to search for solutions but I don't think it matches my problem.

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: Start easy. Do you know how to create a random number between 0 (including) and 10 (excluding)? How about a random number between, say, 65 and  91 or between 97 and 123? Do you know how to turn a number into an (ascii) character? Do you know how to iterate over each character of a string (like the given pattern)? Do you know how to switch a workflow based on a certain value (of a character)? Do you know how to combine characters into a string?

Answer (score 0):

We make functions for generating uppercase and lowercase letters, we also do a quick generation of numbers and then we just switch on the characters of the passed "pattern" string

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetStringFromPattern("!!##??##!!"));
    }
    static string GetStringFromPattern(string s)
    {
        string final = String.Empty;
        foreach(char c in s)
        {
            switch (c)
            {
                case '!':
                    Random rng = new Random();
                    final += rng.Next(0, 9);
                    break;
                case '#':
                    final += GenerateLetter(true);
                    break;
                case '?':
                    final += GenerateLetter(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return final;
    }

    static char GenerateLetter(bool uppercase)
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int letterCode = rng.Next(65, 89);

        if (uppercase)
            letterCode += 32;

        char letter = (char)letterCode;

        return letter;
    }

}
```

Comment: One Random object can generate an infinite number of values - do not create them in a loop.

Comment: and may I ask how to make it return a new letter every time? @Krystian

Comment: @vexisz: first as Nyssa pointed out, you should have only have one instance of Random. If you create one very soon after another, it will return the same sequence of *pseudo random* numbers. Secondly, it's important to know that random numbers may repeat (if you are playing a game with dice, no one is surprised if two (or even 3) rolls in a row show up with the same value). It shouldn't happen regularly, but it will happen